# Jquery, Getting the value of a input type="file" field

Tags: jquery, forms

Can anybody let me know if there is anything wrong with the following code. I'm trying to get the value of a input type="file" form tag but the alert keeps telling me it's empty

```
$('#submitForm').bind("click",function(){ 

     var imgVal = $('#imageUpload').val(); 
 alert(imgVal);             
 return false;
});

<input name="imageUpload" id="imageUpload" type="file" value="" class="text"/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submitForm" value="Submit Photo" />
```

Thanks in advance

James

Comment: Sorry to bother you guys. It turns out I gave my form the same ID as the input field. Cheers

Comment: Either post an answer yourself or press *delete* link below the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me.

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/tnXpP/)***:

```
$('#submitForm').bind("click",function() { 

    var imgVal = $('#imageUpload').val(); 
    alert(imgVal);             
    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work on any browser

```
$('#imageUpload').attr('value')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do: 
`var imgVal = document.getElementById("imageUpload");`
Then to get the value do something like this: 
`alert(imgVal.value);`

One thing to remember is that many browsers will give you the file, but it will hide the actual path with something like this:
`C:/fakepath/filename.extension`

Answer (score 0):

when any user select file then to detect in jquery is file element value change or not 
put this code in jQuery file

```html
$(document).ready(function()
{
 //$("#upload").attr("disabled","true");
 $("#upload").attr("disabled","disabled");
 
 $("#file").change(function()
 {
  //alert("someting change");
  //value =  $(this).val();//get fake path of file
  //alert(value);
  $("#upload").removeAttr("disabled"); //enabling upload button
  
  
 });
 
});
```

file type button is enable and upload button of form is disable when user will select file then it's value will change and enable upload button which means then we can submit our form.

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
$('#imageUpload').value
```

Comment: Incorrect, this outputs `undefined`. Since you're querying the element with jQuery, you'd want to use `.val()` instead of `.value`. If you _really wanted_ to use jQuery (for instance selecting the element and doing other things via chaining before getting the value), you could end with `[0].value`.